# Blackjack Card Display Issue

Tags: android-studio

For my App Dev 2 project, we were told to make a basic Blackjack game on Android Studio. The problems revolve around the Stand button. Anytime I press it, the app closes. Another issue is that whenever the button does work, it will replace the dealer's first card with their second card, when I need the second facedown card to be replaced with the second faceup card. I will link everything pertaining to this issue, as the whole program is too large for stackoverflow.

```js
    public ImageView dealer_Card1, dealer_Card2, dealer_Card3, dealer_Card4, dealer_Card5;

    public ImageView player_Card1, player_Card2, player_Card3, player_Card4, player_Card5;
    
    public void btn_Stand_Click() {
        do {
            dealer_Call();
            calculate_Dealer_Score();

            if (dealer_Score > 21) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    if (dealer_Card_Array[i] == 'A' && dealer_Score_Count[i] == 11) {
                        dealer_Score_Count[i] = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                calculate_Dealer_Score();
            }
        } while (dealer_Score < 17 && dealer_Score <= player_Score && dealer_Card_Number < 5);
        results();
    }

    public void btn_Stand(View view) {
        do {
            dealer_Call();
            calculate_Dealer_Score();

            if (dealer_Score > 21) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    if (dealer_Card_Array[i] == 'A' && dealer_Score_Count[i] == 11) {
                        dealer_Score_Count[i] = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                calculate_Dealer_Score();
            }
        } while (dealer_Score < 17 && dealer_Score <= player_Score && dealer_Card_Number < 5);

        if (player_Score == 21) {
            black_Jack();
        } else if (dealer_Score == 21) {
            dealer_black_Jack();
        } else if (dealer_Score > 21) {
            total = total + (bet * 2);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dealer Bust! You won!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
            disable_Buttons();
            alert_Box();
        } else results();
    }
    
     private void card_Image_Switcher() {

        dealer_Card1.setImageResource(R.drawable.cardback);
        dealer_Card2.setImageResource(R.drawable.cardback);
        dealer_Card3.setImageResource(R.drawable.cardback);
        dealer_Card4.setImageResource(R.drawable.cardback);
        dealer_Card5.setImageResource(R.drawable.cardback);

        player_Card1.setImageResource(R.drawable.cardback);
        player_Card2.setImageResource(R.drawable.cardback);
        player_Card3.setImageResource(R.drawable.cardback);
        player_Card4.setImageResource(R.drawable.cardback);
        player_Card5.setImageResource(R.drawable.cardback);
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to post your log cat so we can see what the error is that is causing the crash.

Comment: 12-07 20:36:33.896 4390-4390/com.example.chan.blackjack E/chromium: [ERROR:interface_registry.cc(104)] Failed to locate a binder for interface: autofill::mojom::PasswordManagerDriver
12-07 20:36:33.902 4390-4512/com.example.chan.blackjack E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)